# Codeception Api Test gives error in Yii2

Tags: yii2, codeception

I have below YML code in **api.suite.yml**

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
    enabled: [PhpBrowser, REST]
    depends: 
         REST: PhpBrowser
    config:
        PhpBrowser:
            url: 'http://localhost/testapi/'
        REST:
            url: 'http://localhost/testapi/json/1.0/'
```

It gives below error when I run using **./vendor/bin/codecept run**

```
  [Codeception\Exception\ModuleRequireException]              
  REST module requirements are not met!                       
  This module depends on Codeception\Lib\InnerBrowser         

  Example configuring PhpBrowser as backend for REST module.  
  --                                                          
  modules:                                                    
      enabled: REST:                                          
          depends: PhpBrowser                                 
          url: http://localhost/api/                          
  --                                                          
  Framework modules can be used for testing of API as well.
```

I tried many YML config combinations without any luck. How to fix this issue?

Comment: Your config looks ok. Have you tried running `codecept build`?

Comment: yes.. I already tried that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same exception. After doing some research, if could fix my issue with the following configuration:

```
class_name: ApiTester
modules:
  enabled:
    - REST:
        depends: PhpBrowser
        url: http://127.0.0.1/api/v1/
```

Yaml files are whitespace-sensitive. So you have to pay attention on the indentations.